# Loading a timeline from a social network efficiently

Tags: postgresql, join

I tried to attack this problem using the classical JOIN operation: I have a table Posts and a table Followings, so given a user_id I retrieve its followings and get the posts of those followings by joining both tables. Until here it's fine.

Since it's a timeline, I need to establish a number of posts retrieve, let's say 30. There will be a button to retrieve the previous 30 posts and so on, which means that I need to retrieve the timeline in chunks of 30 posts.

The problems comes when thinking about efficiency. I'm not an expert on DBs but I remember that on MySQL you can do something like this (I don't know how it's in PostgreSQL though):

```
SELECT * FROM [... join ...] LIMIT 0,30
SELECT * FROM [... join ...] LIMIT 30,60
SELECT * FROM [... join ...] LIMIT 60,90
```

I guess that internally it's performing the join operation, consequently obtaining all rows to later retrieve a limited number of rows. The problem is that in this example it is repeating the same join operation 3 times and I was wondering if there is a way to force the database to store in a cache that join result so that the join operation is only performed once and then the result is limited afterwards, or, on the other hand, I would like to know if there is no way I can avoid performing joins all the time in each query.

Edit: I'm interested in a PostgreSQL solution.

Thanks.

Comment: implementation will differ in postgres and mysql - if you want affective solution make up your mind

Comment: Sorry for not being specific on that. I'm interested in Postgres but I only new how to illustrate it with mysql syntax. Thanks.

Comment: there's often quoted article on pagination  https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/